# Smooth e simultaneously animation of 2 divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have 2 divs. One of them has to be hidden once user click on a link and in the same time the other one has to be shown.
I suppose I can do this with jQuery, but my code hide the first div in more or less 0.5 second but in the same time it shows the second div above it immediatly. Once the first one has been hidden, the second one takes its place in a rough way creating a flicker in the animation. How can I do it smoothly and continuously?

What I need is that the second div appears only once the first one is disappeared, both with a fade. In other words, I need a soft transition.

Here my jQuery code:

```
$("#skip_step2creator").click(function() {
    $(".form_step2creator").fadeOut();
    $(".form_step3creator").css({display: "block"}).animate({opacity: 1.0});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form_step2creator">
<p>Content</p>
</div

<div class="form_step3creator">
<p>Content</p>
</div
```

CSS:

```
.form_step3creator {display: none;}
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to use the callbacks from the `fadeOut()` and `animate()` methods. Could you please add the relevant HTML and CSS to the question so we can see the exact issue you describe.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just edit it so you can see my basic code. Thanks.

Comment: `$(".form_step2creator").fadeOut(() => $(".form_step3creator").fadeIn());`

Comment: Display property can not be animated with time. You can try using position absolute and zIndex if you want to stack the divs and do animations.

Comment: @freedomn-m I choosed your code because of its simplicity and it works very well! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the callback available to the `.fadeOut()` method. The callback is invoked after the animation is done, so you can simply move the logic dealing with `.form_step3creator` into the callback instead.

Also, you can just use `.fadeIn()` instead of having to toggle the CSS display property + animate in the opacity.

See proof-of-concept example:

```js
$("#skip_step2creator").click(function() {
  $(".form_step2creator").fadeOut(function() {
    $(".form_step3creator").fadeIn();
  });

});
```

```css
.form_step3creator {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="skip_step2creator">Skip</button>
<div class="form_step2creator">
  <p>form_step2creator</p>
</div>
<div class="form_step3creator">
  <p>form_step3creator</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's the same solution of freedomn-m, but written in a different way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For future users, the freedomn-m solution works very well:

```
$(".form_step2creator").fadeOut(() => $(".form_step3creator").fadeIn());
```